# Uipath(RPA) : swap the two columns in excel

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot

I'm try to **swap** a data **between two columns** in **excel**,but i'm facing the issues.

[image: Main File]

[image: Error]

Comment: You want to move just a single cell from column to column? Or the whole column to switch?

Comment: whole column to switch?

Comment: Tell us what you really need. Make an example before and one after the change. That makes it easier to get what you really need.